# Files not appearing - caching or?

Tags: windows-7, files

I'm going to try to describe an effect we're seeing, hopefully this will be useful enough to gather an answer. If there is a duplicate, I will accept that I missed it and delete this question.

Using Windows 7 at work, we have a user who has a shortcut on his desktop, pointing to G:\netapps\office\manager_files. If he double clicks on the shortcut, he gets a file manager window, opened directly to the manager_files location. Let's say he opened it this morning, took a look, and then closed file manager.

Now I open file manager where I have G: mapped. I drill down to the same location and from my desktop, I drag and drop (copy) a file into that location. I inform my manager that I have done so.

He opens his shortcut, and then yells at me because it's not there. I patiently explain that if he were to hit F5 (refresh), it would be very helpful. Now he yells at me that I need to fix it so he doesn't have to do that (refresh).

Is there a setting (GPO or other) we can set to cause immediate refreshing? If so, is there a serious (networkish, or system cpu utilizationish) reason not to do so?

My problem here is I don't know how to word the Google search for this.

Comment: Hit the user in the head with a blunt object until the st00pid falls out the other side.  Seriously.  This is a "people problem," and people problems don't get fixed with technical tweaks.

Comment: Auto-refreshing probably has a technical solution.  A yelling boss, no.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman A user who can't refresh a window when looking for a new file is absolutely a "people problem." (Nor is this specific use-case the only place the underlying "people problem" is going to rear its head, but I digress...) More importantly, the fixes available to make Windows 7's Windows Explorer auto-refresh are pretty hit-and-miss, and inconsistent. They'll work for a while, or for certain folders, then they won't, etc... it's simply unreliable.  The only reliable way to refresh the Windows Explorer Window... is to actually refresh it.

Comment: However, we just replicated the issue in which F5 (or right-click-refresh) did NOT help. Sorting the folder (or more specifically re-sorting the same way) did.

Answer (score 2):

There are Windows Explorer settings that can cause Explorer not to refresh.  You may want check that.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]  
"NoRemoteRecursiveEvents"=dword:00000001  

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]  
"NoRemoteChangeNotify"=dword:00000001
```

There is also a known issue where the SMB directory cache may not be updated correctly.  You may want to update the Windows 7 client with the latest MRXSMB component files and test to see if the issue still occurs.

List of currently available hotfixes for the File Services technologies in Windows Server 2008/2008 R2
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2473205